# Is it safe to use a lawn mower blade in an angle grinder?

Tags: safety

Is it sufficient to remove the guards and bolt on a lawn mower blade, or should I find a different mechanism to secure it?

Comment: How many fingers do you still have?  Do you really want something sharp spinning at 1000s of RPMs less than an inch from your fingers/body.

Comment: This is an ironic question stemming from a debate about the definition of "subjective" in [another post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/250798/how-can-i-use-a-plunge-router-on-a-vertical-surface). It's not a serious question. Obviously.

Comment: @isherwood  Are you really sure it is ironic?

Comment: I'm objectively positive this similar question didn't get closed or downvoted due to @isherwood's involvement.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86591/is-it-safe-to-use-an-angle-grinder-with-wood-cutting-blades  The evidence is right there.

Comment: I'm sure I appreciate a meta-laugh, but sometimes people that aren't in on the joke aren't in on the joke. Maybe we just close this one...

Comment: Do it, but fill out your Darwin Award Application Form first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Voted. Folks who do chainsaw wood carving subjectively don't think that would be unsafe.

Comment: Your hypothetical carver is ignoring real facts about angle grinders.

Comment: Don't be like [this guy](https://www.facebook.com/reel/705789387322846/?s=single_unit).

Answer (score 4):

**No.** This is, quite frankly, a bad idea.

Maybe if you explained what you were trying to accomplish in a different question, you might get useful information.

Comment: Don't think stupid is even close enough.